# Why are my express router.get URL's with multiple paths rendering text only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm currently trying to set up a password reset flow using Pug (formerly known as Jade) and Express.

For some reason GET requests including URL's with multiple paths appended will render my pug views files with text only. No images or style is loaded.

For example:

```
app.get('/example', (req, res) => {
    res.render('test')
})
```

will render the test file with style and images perfectly. However:

```
app.get('/example/test', (req, res) => {
    res.render('test')
})
```

will render the test file with text only. Images and style missing.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Are your image urls like `images/one.jpg` etc?..  If so when you go to `/example/test` the url will become `/example/images/one.jpg`...  Try making your urls absolute `/images/one.jpg`.. etc.

Comment: Haha no way, you were right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add `app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));` in your `server.js`.
2. create a new folder called `public` on your `workspace` where your `server.js` exists.
3. Now create  `styles` and `images` folders inside `public` and put your css files and images files inside each folder.
4. change your path of css on `test.html` to `/styles/test.css` for example. You should have it work now.

The static method defined in `express` will look for `public`folder as the absolute root path  and now no matter how many layers of route calls you get you can access to your `styles` and `images` folders without the need to back trace the relative path of your css/images files.